# Windows / smb share

Tags: networking, files, samba

To start, this OS is really great. I only have 1 rather big problem. I can not save files to my Ubuntu server.

Connecting to a smb share or sftp share is not a problem with the 'files' app. I can create files, or directory's.

Problem with saving files in Scratch app: 'you cannot save changes on file ...' The same problem with LibreOffice writer when saving a new file. With LibreOffice writer, existing files will not even open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed gedit, which doesn't give any problems. So the problem is in LibreOffice and Scratch! Can anyone confirm?

I installed LibreOffcice from the appcenter. This is

Version: 5.1.6.2
Build ID: 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial3
CPU Threads: 4; OS Version: Linux 4.13; UI Render: default; 
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); Calc: group

After this I removed LibreOffice and downloaded the software from the website. Installed this and problem solved. 
If someone would like to know how to install this manually, follow this videolink on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8XXJ5GHiJg

Comment: There is no any problems saving files with Scratch unless I'm trying to save a read only file, or a file in a location where I have no write access. Same with Libre office and Sublime text editors